# SAS proc summary types alternative in Pandas

Tags: pandas, types, sas, pandas-groupby, summary

I'm searching for a Pandas alternative to ***types*** statement in SAS PROC SUMMARY.
Simply speaking, each line in ***types*** is an individual groupby.
The output result is one table with all the requested types summary.

A loop with different groupby inputs could be a solution, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it in Pandas?

```
proc summary data=inDS;
    class A B C D E;
    types
        A * B * C
        A * B * D
        A * B * E
        A * B
        A
    ;
    var sales;
    output out=outDS  sum= ;
run;
```

Comment: `TYPES` is a statement. Do you want to parse distributive expressions such as `A * B * ( C D E )` ?

Comment: thanks for the correction on types. Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: `SUMMARY` can parse a types crossing expression such as `A * B * ( C D E )`, which, when expanded by the distributive property, corresponds to the three individual crossings `A*B*C`, `A*B*D`, `A*B*E` (as shown in your question).

Comment: I'm asking for "proc summary types" alternative in Python Pandas. I'm not sure how your comment is related to my initial question.

Comment: I see that this question is old. Did you ever find a good a simple way to do this? I too am trying to find a pandas way to evaluate aggregate values for all combination of class vars. Coming from a SAS background was hoping there would be a similar solution.